# Mysql Cluster in Windows

Tags: windows, mysql-cluster

I am trying to use MySQL Cluster 7.5 version , after opening the web browser and clicking on :create new MySQL cluster", and getting in the "define cluster" page , I write the IP of the remote data node in to  the host list field ,but I get error which say "there were errors when connecting to the remote hosts, host 172.16.1.129: couldn't open socket to 172.16.1.129 ,press'ok to continue to the next page anyway, or cancel to stay in the previous page"

I turned off windows firewall options too, but no luck,

what is the cause of this error and how to solve it? 
What are the essential steps to install/configure in remote pc (data node).?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/cluster.html

Did you check this? if you OS supports?

Comment: Please share a summary of what the link points to along with the link. This way your answer stays relevant even after the link goes dead.

Comment: Hi Anton, Windows 10 supported for mysql cluster 7.5.

Comment: Hi Sinstein , Simply i am trying to do ndb cluster with 3 nodes in windows platform through auto installer, One Mangament Node , two data nodes , I tried to enter management node ipaddress and data node ip address in Host fied, But Resouce info column showing 'Failed' , Its Ok only for localhost,

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with supported platforms. My guess is the credentials you used to connect to nodes are bad. In that version of MySQL NDB Cluster autoinstaller you can provide only Cluster-wide credentials, i.e. one credentials for all the hosts. Those credentials could be a) private key *without* passphrase (idrsa in ~/.ssh) or b) ordinary username/password. Please see html help file that comes with Autoinstaller for details.

Comment: Hi Tonci, thanks for commenting, I will check the help file